# XhrManager Bad Request status 400 - closure-library

Tags: google-closure-library

I am using goog.net.XhrManager to send PUT requests to create resources on server with the following data:

PUT {"name": "product name", "hack": "invalid input"}

The server response status is 400 - Bad Request because "hack" is an invalid property of the product resource.

Everything is OK except that the browser console log an error message with:

**PUT "http://myserver/datastore/product" 400 (OK)** with the method call stack.

How to prevent that XhrManager and XhrIo to log this error on console?

The Bad Request is already handled by the callback on XhrManager.send() and the end-user should not know that an error occurred.

Client side validation is an option that works for bad requests.

How to handle conflicts and other responses on client side without flood the browser console with error messages that the client is completely capable of solving?

Uniqueness of user email on create new account (conflict - status 409)
Update a resource that is outdated on client (version conflict - status 409)
Unauthorized resource access (status 401)